# Sluggish scrolling experience when using QuartzCore to round corners on UIImageView's within a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, quartz-graphics

I use `QuartzCore` to add rounded corners to my `UIImageView`'s within the cells of my `UITableView`

This is the code that I use:

```
fooImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0;
fooImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
fooImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

The problem is that when I add this code. The table cells movement is slowed down dramatically. I'm just wondering whether there are other alternatives to make the user experience much faster and to increase performance when scrolling a table view cell using this technique?

I see a lot of applications (most Twitter apps) that have no performance decrease when having rounded corners applied to images within their cells. Just wondering how they overcome the "sluggishness"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are 3 main techniques for improving UITableView performance that I use:

1. Always reuse cells, use the
   dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier
   when creating new cells.  This
   prevents the overhead of the OS
   creating and destroying lots of
   objects when scrolling fast.
2. Collapse the view hierarchy of the
   cell.  Instead of having lots of
   views and subviews, create a custom
   view and do all your cell drawing in
   the drawRect.  Apps like Twitter use
   this approach for super fast cell drawing.
3. Ensure your images are opaque.  You can do this by ensuring all image assets don't have alpha channels baked into them and by setting the layer's opaque property to YES.

Examples:

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath (the table identifier string simply creates a reference to cells that are the same type and can be anything you like):

```
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
// Create a new cell if necessary
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Check out the following link for examples of improving performance of UITableViews: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Hope this helps,

Dave

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Are you able to provide examples on dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier? Also are you able to elaborate on the cell drawing in drawRect?

Comment: @Fulvio No problem, some examples edited into the post above.  To track down opacity performance issues you can run your code under instruments and use the CoreAnimation instrument.  This will colour areas of your cell in red that are performing poorly.  Cheers Dave.

Comment: Thanks for the code example. It's exactly how I construct my cellForRowAtIndexPath in the first place. So I'm good there. I will check out the sample code you've provided and look at other alternatives.

Answer (score 15):

The first thing I would try doing is setting:

```
fooImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

This renders the rounded corner effect as a bitmap. I had some similar issues when using CALayer effects on views in a `UIScrollView` a while back, and this setting drastically improved performance.

Don't forget to set

```
fooImageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

to prevent pixelation (rasterization at the wrong resolution for the device).

Comment: I will also try this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In my case it imediately added 15 FPS! The drawback is image quality in the image view inside cell :(

Comment: @Stuart . Are there any other things to be done for smooth scrolling. I am working with an app full of images inside tableviewcell.

Answer (score 2):

You could do some masking. Overlaying the images with a mask-image that has a rounded corners square cut out from it and it will work like a charm.

Also be sure to use reuseCellIdentifier otherwise the table will lag if it gets even a little complex.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: set cells opaque and draw them yourself.

Follow the advice by StuDave and Magic Bullet, and see also [Fast Scrolling in Tweetie with UITableView](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) by the author of the official Twitter client ot learn how to do cell drawing. It's a simple and clear example project.

Beyond solving this specific issue, you should read [UITableView construction, drawing and management (revisited)](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html) by Matt Gallagher to learn how to write custom table controllers and cells. This not only improves the performance of your code, it lets you do things which are not possible with the standard classes from Apple. Basically you will create an `UIViewController` that replicates key methods of the `UITableViewController`.

Comment: link is dead :( any way to retrieve it somehow?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20100322222950/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/ https://github.com/enormego/ABTableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

In my case it added endless subviews and the table view slowed down dramatically exactly as you said. I added this logic in `willDisplayCell` to fix the problem:

```
if cell.contentView.subviews.count < 3 /* elements in cell + subviews */  { 

        cell.contentView.addSubview(subView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(subView)

 }
```